# JSON array won't decode?

Tags: php, json

The JSON apparently looks likes this.

```
    {\"amount\":10,\"conversion_id\":\"5145fd4e04af9\",\"extra_params\":
    {\"ip\":\"99.237.185.67\",\"user_agent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
    AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 
    Safari/537.11\"},\"job_title\":\"Answer a few questions about a website (Canada - 
    Sunday task #1) (Canada Only)\",\"adjusted_amount\":8.0}
```

But json_decode won't work in php. HELP???

Comment: The JSON is invalid. Keys must be strings, i.e. in double quotes. Fix that and `json_decode` will work.

Comment: You can use http://www.jslint.com/ to validate your json.. It should be    {
    "payload": {
    "conversion_id": "32402345984532934511",
    "amount": 50,
    "adjusted_amount": 25,
    "job_title": "The title of the last job they completed (and 2 other jobs)"
    },
    "signature": "1221299611f823b8c30a347373b449ad"
    }

Comment: It's also invalid with `\"`.

Answer (score 3):

That is not valid JSON. In JSON keys must be quoted with `"`, so your stuff as JSON would be

```
{
    "payload": {
        "conversion_id": "32402345984532934511",
        "amount": 50,
        "adjusted_amount": 25,
        "job_title": "The title of the last job they completed (and 2 other jobs)"
    },
    "signature": "1221299611f823b8c30a347373b449ad"
}
```

Also see http://json.org

Comment: Additionally you might want to take a look into RFC 4627 (see: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). This is where the JSON format is specified. Although a lot of implementations allow non-string formatted keys as shortcut to save some typing it's not in the standard.